# Swift Firebase Send Verification Email with apple login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to send an E-Mail verification with a normal (E-Mail/Password registered user), I receive it.

When I send a verification Mail with an Apple Login registered user and he doesn't hide the email, it also works.

But when I try to send a verification Mail with an Apple Login registered user and he hides the email, I don't receive it.

I thought firebase would forward this email to the real email address??

The E-Mail I get from the user looks like this: mxrjzhdxky@privaterelay.appleid.com

My code:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser!.sendEmailVerification { error in
   if let error = error {
      print("Error of Verification email: \(String(describing: error.localizedDescription))")
   }
   print("Email sent")
}
```

I also get the "Email sent" text in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase can’t forward to “real” email id.
Firebase can send it to the given email and only Apple can forward it to the real email, but based on user’s settings.

Comment: That means that the user has to change his settings, such that he receives the email?

Comment: Yes, in this case, Apple is explicitly masking user’s email. Forwarding your mail to “real” email of user is contract between user and Apple.